# Chrome extension which could inject dynamically-updated CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, mastodon

I was considering creating an extension to hide specific Mastodon posts. Let's say I’m afraid of snakes and want to make sure I can hide any post with a pic of a snake in it (I'm already filtering by the word).

- Each post has a `data-id` by which it can be styled.
- For a one-off, that's all I need, I can hide it with Javascript
- But to make the change persistent, I would need to have a CSS injected with `display:none` for all the posts I’ve hidden (or a `<style>` element in the DOM?)
- So I would need to have an extension which could add a line to a CSS file, or which would pull the CSS dynamically from a database, or write out a new local file from a database when a new post was hidden

Which of those things is even possible? Can an extension rewrite its own files?

Comment: In the js content script you can create a style element and set its textContent according to the contents of chrome.storage.local, which is configured by the user in the action popup or options page.

Comment: There's existing extensions which can do this (meaning both inject CSS, and also dynamically update the DOM based on a user-defined script) check out TamperMonkey and/or Stylish